# mail delivery issue in woocommerce website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gmail

I am using a GoDaddy server for a Woocommerce website. in this case, if I purchase something the mail notification to customer works perfectly. but the admin didn't get any mail. I checked it with log mail plugin all emails are successfully sent from the website but it didn't reach in the recipient side.

How can I solve the issue or how can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check that your SMTP settings match GoDaddy's [instructions](https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953). However, even if that fixes the immediate problem, it might be worth checking that GoDaddy's mail looks ok to mail services using something like [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) or [Mail Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/).

Comment: thanks for your reply. some of our emails work fine. but some admin emails not works. is there is any chance SMTP settings issue??

Comment: I think it's very likely an SMTP/deliverability issue because you found them successfully sent in the mail log. So it's probably just the admin's email account is more aggressively filtering the mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WP forms, You can try with it's add-on "WP Mail SMTP by WPForms"
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ it will work for sure.